# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre <!DOCTYPE html> en mayúsculas y <!doctype html> en minúsculas?

Tags: html, html5

Veo que en *HTML* se usa `<!DOCTYPE html>`, la palabra `DOCTYPE` está en mayúsculas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />`
```

Pero también es posible usar `<!doctype html>`, con la palabra `doctype` en minúsculas:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />`
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Puede haber problemas al usar el `doctype` en minúsculas? ¿Existe alguna explicación de por qué siempre se usa en mayúscula?

Al mirar el código fuente de una página que lo use en minúsculas, no noto ningún problema, pero quizás haya alguna parte oculta del motor que pueda dar problemas al hacer esto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si revisamos la [lista recomendada de declaraciones del *doctype*](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) notamos que:

- El **recomendado** es `DOCTYPE html` para que de esta forma el documento sea *parseado* de la misma forma en cualquier navegador

Sin embargo se ofrecen otros tantos tales como los que puedes leer más abajo:

Para HTML5 y superior

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Para HTML4 en modo estricto

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Para HTML4 transicional

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Para HTML4 Frameset

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

Y muchos más, pero considero que están prácticamente obsoletos y ya no es relevante colocarlos

Es importante notar que para la **HTML Living Standar** el uso del *doctype* es:

- Por razones de legado y asegurar lo ya mencionado más arriba en la uniformidad de la interpretación del documento por distintos navegadores

Aún más importante y cito<sup>1</sup>

> A DOCTYPE must consist of the following components, in this order:

- A string that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "

  One or more ASCII whitespace.

  A string that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "html".

  Optionally, a DOCTYPE legacy string.

  Zero or more ASCII whitespace. A U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN character (>).

> **In other words, , case-insensitively.**

Lo más importante está debajo

> En otras palabras el *doctype* no es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas

**Referencias**

- 1[HTML Doctype](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype)

Answer (score 1):

Para *HTML* eso no importa, ya que no distingue ni mayúscula ni minúscula.

Estos formatos son válidos:

```
<!doctype html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DoCtYpE hTmL>
```

Por cierto, esta pregunta se ha respondido en *StackOverflow en inglés* con más detalle: [Uppercase or lowercase doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020961/uppercase-or-lowercase-doctypepr)